# Budget planning and maintenance

Tags: windows, finance

I'm looking for a software that can be used to keep track of a budget for a company.

It should enable users to read and/or edit the budget. And if possible, it should support audit trial.

The main reason to use a software for budget is to reduce administrative work, time, and reduce misinterpretation.

The data from the system will be used for business intelligence.

We are using Windows. We are about 15 people. The cost doesn't matter.

Comment: If access levels are your only requirement I think pretty much any budgeting software will work.  Could you add some requirements to this?  What will you be using it for, what functionality is required, what would be nice to have, etc.

Comment: Im newbie in this area and i dont so much about it either about requirement specification. I need to look a sample of a budget application to understand better.

Comment: This may help get you started.  http://www.softwareadvice.com/accounting/budgeting-forecasting-software-comparison/

Comment: Can you tell something more about the process? I have been selling and implementing budgeting software a lot for both project-based companies as well as more traditional business form (year budgets) and from my experience there are many variations in the needs. Please state how the budget should be allocated, released and by what segmentation (project, cost category, general ledger account, company, person, department, product type). In general: almost any serious ERP package has this functionality (Axapta, JDEdwards, SAP) and some smaller products offer the same.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Today I don't have all the requirments in my hand. We are now in a immature phase.

Comment: Otherwise I will suggest SAP :-) *shudder*

Answer (score 0):

I have recently started using [YNAB](http://www.youneedabudget.com/) to keep track of my personal budget.

- You could enable users by sharing the folder on Dropbox.  Which might not be tight enough control for what you need.

This budgeting software really works best if you apply there budgeting rules.